# Sarcastic “Surprise, surprise” equivalent for informal French?

Tags: expressions, argot, langage-informel, langage-des-jeunes, ironie

Is there anything in French like saying “Surprise, surprise!” sarcastically?

*“Oh, he bought ANOTHER Nintendo game.”*

*“Surprise, surprise. It’s all he does.”*

Wordreference gave me “Comme par hasard” but I don’t know how widespread/accurate that is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Comme par hasard* (or the variant *comme de par hasard* - considered as faulty but still used, sometimes for a humorous effect) would rather fit as an ironical comment in situations where you suspect someone has a hidden agenda and you rather think there is no *hasard* (in the sens of coincidence).

> -Je suis désolé, j'ai oublié mon portefeuille.
>
> -Comme par hasard ! Et je suppose que je vais devoir payer alors ?

As in your example, if you want to express that an event or a situation is not surprising at all (without this sense of getting suspicious at an alleged coincidence), you can say:

> Evidemment !
>
> Ben tiens !
>
> Voyez-vous ça ! (a bit old-fashioned)

Or on the tone of irony:

> Quelle surprise !
>
> Tu m'étonnes !
>
> Sans blague ! (variants: sans rire / sans déconner / sans déc)

Comment: You might consider adding  « Comme de par hasard » that most people consider as not good French, it is very informal indeed, but at least not ambiguous - it is always ironical.

Comment: True ! I'll add it, thanks.